# Forward-leaning random numbers' probability distribution

Tags: algorithm, random, probability

Say I'm pseudo-randomly picking a number from 1 to 50 every second for 100 seconds, and as time goes on the number picked is more likely to be greater. How could I structure such an algorithm?

For example: after 99 seconds the probability of choosing a number closer to 50 is much more likely than choosing a number closer to 1.

Or: the number picked after 10 seconds is more likely to be greater than the number picked after 9 seconds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a simple solution for you. Instead of `rand(1, 50)` (say this function generates uniformly random numbers 1..50) use this expression:

```
power(rand(1, power(50, exp)), 1/exp)
```

this will still give you all the numbers 1..50. For `exp = 1`, the distribution will be uniform. As you slightly increase exp (e.g. like 1.1 or so), the probability of getting larger numbers will increase. The higher the exp, the more it will increase towards 50.

So you can do e.g.:

```
factor = 1 /* finetune this for your needs */
for second = 0..100
    exp = 1 + (second / 100) * factor
    rand_num = power(rand(1, power(50, exp)), 1/exp)
endfor
```

Answer (score 5):

Pick any concave monotonic function like square root which maps 0 to 0 and 1 to 1. Generate a random number between [0,1], apply the function and then scretch [0,1] to the desired interval ([1,50]).

Now if you morph from the linear transformation f(x)=x to the mentioned transform function with for example a simple weighting you have the desired effect.

Comment: @yi_H Not sure I fully understand. But your function need to change for each second. Fond example let's take the serie of function f(i,x) = pow(x,1/i), it starts zith f(x)=x then f(x)=sqrt(x) ... and it does what you want . You cannot stick with one function for all seconds (otherwise the probability as no reason to increase). right ?

Comment: yes, you can take a series of functions or as I wrote you can morph between them. f(x) = (1-i)x + i sqrt(x), where i goes from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudocode:

```
let i = 0
let n = 50 // Adjust for your needs
for i goes to 100 {
  randomnum = int(sqrt(rand(1, 50*n)));
}
```

This can be very forward-leaning, but it's one way to approach it.

Thanks to Ricky Bobby for pointing out a fundamental problem with my old approach. This is inspired by yi_H's suggestion of using a function like sqrt.

Comment: not sure it works for any rand function.if rand is uniform at each step the probability is still uniform  (the probability of picking 1 is the same as 51 wich is the same as 50 even you eliminate number above 50) . Or i'm mising something ?

Comment: I believe the concave function need to evoluate with i, otherwise the probability distribution is the same at all time. You can use randomnum int(50*pow(rand(),1/i))

Comment: I give you a +1 because I really find your first approach interesting even if it was false. Tomas Telensky has the right answer .

Answer (score 0):

There are probably simpler ways for what you're doing, but the general solution is to use [inverse transform sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).

Essentially, if you want to produce a random number with a given PDF, *p(x)*, you first calculate the inverse cumulative density function (CDF), *P'(x)*.  You can then generate uniform random numbers between 0 and 1, and then apply *P'(x)* to them.